# PIP installation - Invalid whl file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi, python-wheel

I get the following error message while trying to install any whl package. This is in a newly installed python environment and my first attempt to install a wheel file.

```
# pip3 install -v idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl

Using pip 23.0 from /usr/lpp/python/py311/pyz/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

Processing ./idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl

ERROR: Wheel 'idna' located at /global/data_transfer/idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl is invalid.
```

The python environment is running on a unix system. It doesn't have direct access to internet so I FTPied the file from my workstation to unix.

I tried FTP in both bin and ascii mode.
The module installs fine in another environment but not in mine.

Comment: The error says that your wheel file is invalid. Try to download the compatible version with python3.11.

Comment: What does `file idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl` say? Or `zipinfo idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl`? (Wheels are ZIP files.)

Comment: As per documentation, it is compatible with v3.5 or newer. Also, I am facing this issue with other whl as well.

Comment: It was lame mistake. The files downloaded were corrupted. 
Instead of clicking on download button, I used 'save as' from right click.

Now it works fine. Thanks @shaikmoeed and AFX

Comment: @TheEpicist Great, I have posted the same as an answer, which helped you to fix this issue. If you find it helpful, feel free to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your wheel file is invalid. Try to download the compatible version with `python3.11` (from OP's error logs)